# Swift Collection View inside Table View with empty space

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

I made a swift project open source that is a demo about using Collection View inside Table View Cells.

Everything is working, except a bug in the third cell that has an empty space and i debug it a lot and don't find any solution.

A screenshot:

[image: bug]

The project:
https://github.com/prsolucoes/TableWithCollection

This issue with a video:
https://github.com/prsolucoes/TableWithCollection/issues/1

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In ViewController createAll() function, you need to remove this line:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = max(UIScreen.main.bounds.width, UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
```

I assume it's setting the first nonvisible row (3) when loading the UITableView with double the height. Because using your code after scrolling and coming back it worked fine.

Comment: Hi. I already tried it. Is solve this problem and create other, because if force 14 cells be rendered. Only console i get message "Category rendered: X". From 1 to 14. Im trying find other solution.

Comment: But what exactly is the issue here, do you want to render from 1 to 20? or only the first one?

Comment: The perfect world is render only the visible part (first two rows) and not the others and the cell have the correct size like first row. What i don't understand and don't make sense is that row 3 and others are not rendered but only the third row have the problem.